# How can I receive array which is return by function in apps script to JavaScript?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-api, google-sheets-api

An Apps Script function is returning array value and I'm unbale to receive it in JavaScript, is there any way to fetch it.

Answer (score 0):

#### Answer:

*To pass a value from a Google Apps Script function to JavaScript, you will need to use a success handler.*

#### More Information:

[As per the documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/reference/run#withsuccesshandlerfunction) for `google.script.run`, in order to read a value that is returned from a Google Apps Script function to JavaScript, you will need to handle the successful execution of the GAS function using the `withSuccessHandler` method.

This sets a callback function to which to pass the return value from GAS on completion.

#### Example:

In your Google Apps Script function, you want to return the data that you wish to see in JavaScript.

**Code.gs:**

```js
function getCellValue() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById("sheet-id");
  const sheet = ss.getSheets()[0];

  return sheet.getRange("A1").getValue();
}
```

Then, in the JavaScript side, you will need to use `google.script.run` with the success handler to do something with the return.

**Index.html:**

```html
<div id="displayDiv"></div>
<script>
  // The callback function should be the parameter to pass to the
  // withSuccessHandler method, and the final function call is
  // the name of the function in Google Apps Script to call:

  google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(displayValue).getCellValue()

  // define the callback function:
  function displayValue(value) {
    // get the element wih ID "displayDiv" and set its inner HTML to
    // the value returned by Google Apps Script:
    document.getElementById("displayDiv").innerHTML = value;
  }
</script>
```

#### References:

- [Class google.script.run (Client-side API) | Apps Script](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/reference/run)